# error in retrieving tables in unicode data using Azure/Python

Tags: python, django, encoding, azure

I'm using Azure and the python SDK.

I'm using Azure's table service API for DB interaction.

I've created a table which contains data in unicode (hebrew for example). Creating tables and setting the data in unicode seems to work fine. I'm able to view the data in the database using Azure Storage Explorer and the data is correct.

The problem is when retrieving the data.. Whenever I retrieve specific row, data retrieval works fine for unicoded data:

```
table_service.get_entity("some_table", "partition_key", "row_key")
```

However, when trying to get a number of records using a filter, an encode exception is thrown for any row that has non-ascii chars in it:

```
tasks = table_service.query_entities('some_table', "PartitionKey eq 'partition_key'")
```

Is this a bug on the azure python SDK? Is there a way to set the encoding beforehand so that it won't crash? (azure doesn't give access to sys.setdefaultencoding and using DEFAULT_CHARSET on settings.py doesn't work as well)

I'm using https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/how-to-guides/table-service/ as reference to the table service API

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Python library to me. I whipped up a quick fix and submitted a pull request on GitHub: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/59.

As a workaround for now, feel free to clone my repo (remembering to checkout the dev branch) and install it via `pip install <path-to-repo>/src`.

Caveat: I haven't tested my fix very thoroughly, so you may want to wait for the Microsoft folks to take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I have a contact at Microsoft Azure and I've alerted her about this. Hopefully MS will take care of this bug asap.